# Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<MIDINotification>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<_>'

Tags: swift, coremidi, unsafe-pointers

I am trying to update the code from a CoreMidi exemple I found at http://mattg411.com/swift-coremidi-callbacks/

And the code is date to before Swift 3, so I need to make some ajustement. 
Problem is I have basically never needed to play with unsafe pointers and friends. So I think I have managed to solve a few of the problems, but one them remainsand get me this error `Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<MIDINotification>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<_>'` the code that give this error is `...UnsafePointer<MIDIObjectAddRemoveNotification>(message)`

part of this methode:

```
func MIDIUtil_MIDINotifyProc(message: UnsafePointer<MIDINotification>, refCon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> Void
    {
        let notification:MIDINotification = message.pointee

        if (notification.messageID == .msgObjectAdded || notification.messageID == .msgObjectRemoved)
        {
            let msgPtr:UnsafePointer<MIDIObjectAddRemoveNotification> = UnsafePointer<MIDIObjectAddRemoveNotification>(message)
            let changeMsg:MIDIObjectAddRemoveNotification = msgPtr.pointee
            let h:AnyObject = unbridgeMutable(ptr: refCon)
            let handler:MIDICallbackHandler = h as! MIDICallbackHandler
            handler.processMidiObjectChange(message: changeMsg)
        }
    }
```

EDIT: 
I have created a small project from the few tutorials I found on the net. 
including the fix from  user28434

https://github.com/nissaba/Librarian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood code correctly, line

```
let msgPtr:UnsafePointer<MIDIObjectAddRemoveNotification> = UnsafePointer<MIDIObjectAddRemoveNotification>(message)
```

should rebind memory from `MIDINotification` to `MIDIObjectAddRemoveNotification`.

In Swift 3.0+ you should do it using [`withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafepointer/2430863-withmemoryrebound).

Something like this:

```
let msgPtr:UnsafePointer<MIDIObjectAddRemoveNotification> = message.withMemoryRebound(to: MIDIObjectAddRemoveNotification.self, capacity: 1) { (pointer) in
    return pointer
}
```

Or there's another way: By casting `UnsafePointer` to `UnsafeRawPointer` and then ["assume memory bound"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawpointer/2431721-assumingmemorybound):

```
let msgPtr:UnsafePointer<MIDIObjectAddRemoveNotification> = UnsafeRawPointer(message).assumingMemoryBound(to: MIDIObjectAddRemoveNotification.self)
```

Comment: great the error is now gone thanks. Sadly I get run time crash (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)) from an other part of the code and I don't know if this works as needed. Giving you the answer on this as the erro is gone. I am sad that the CoreMidi API as no swift interface. having to do all the voodoo mombo jumbo to get this working. Hoping to get one day a revamp of it like the AdressBook API got.

Comment: Well, this pointer-type voodoo is legacy of C interface. C lacking inheritance using this as substitute.

Comment: Yes. and it is sad that Apple si not taking the time to wrap it in a user friendly swift API. But that is an other subject.